# Send JSON Array from C# to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, sockets

I would like to send a JSON array object from a c# application to a server running on Javascript.

When I run this code on the client in c#...

```
members = membersList.ToArray();
var bytes = ZeroFormatterSerializer.Serialize(members);
List<byte[]> memberList = new List<byte[]>();
memberList.Add(bytes);

        if (socket != null)
        {
            if (send)
            {
                var objs = new JArray();


                for (int i = 0; i < memberList.Count; i++)
                {
                    var obj = new JObject();
                    obj["members"] = memberList[i];
                    objs.Add(obj);

                }

                socket.Emit("UntangleGS_Serialize", objs);
```

and receive on the server in javascript....

```
socket.on('UntangleGS', function(inputs) {             
    console.log("untangle inputs: ", inputs.members);
```

**I am returned "untangle inputs: undefined," i.e. the error is "undefined"**

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you share the raw data that is being sent? Also, I've never heard of ZeroFormatterSerializer. Is that something custom? Most people just use Utf8Json or Newtonsoft (json.net) to serialize stuff

Comment: Please add `console.log(inputs);` to your client-side code and show what the output is.

Comment: That is not valid json. Whatever you're trying to produce with C# doesn't make any sense to me. Can you give an example of the valid json output you're trying to produce?

Comment: Thanks for the response @JoePhillips, when I use Newtonsoft, I get untangle inputs:  <Buffer 30>
result:  { status: 16, messages: [ 'Edges are not defined' ] }' The c# code is:             `for (int i = 0; i < membersList.Count; i++)
            {
                string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(membersList[i], Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
                byte[] jsonByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                byteList.Add(jsonByte);

            }`

Comment: and @JoePhillips, I'm trying to send an array of integers [0,1,2]

Comment: Thanks for your response @ChrisG, when using `console.log(inputs);`, I get `untangle inputs: [ { members: <Buffer 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00> } ]`

Comment: That's an array, which means you need `inputs[0].members` to access the Buffer. Makes sense, since you're sending an array of three objects, each with a `members` child. You probably want this instead: https://pastebin.com/p8dZfkzr

Comment: @ChrisG many thanks for your help, your suggestion ended up working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you serialise your object ?

[newtonsoft json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)